Optimization of PySpark code to do comparisons of rows
I want to iteratively compare 2 sets of rows in a PySpark dataframe, and find the common values in another column. For example, I have the dataframe (df) below.
Column1  Column2
abc      111
def      666
def      111
tyu      777
abc      777
def      222
tyu      333
ewq      888

The output I want is
abc,def,CommonRow  <-- because of 111
abc,ewq,NoCommonRow
abc,tyu,CommonRow  <-- because of 777
def,ewq,NoCommonRow
def,tyu,NoCommonRow
ewq,tyu,NoCommonRow

The PySpark code that I'm currently using to do this is
# "value_list" contains the unique list of values in Column 1
index = 0
for col1 in value_list:
    index += 1
    df_col1 = df.filter(df.Column1 == col1)
    for col2 in value_list[index:]:
        df_col2 = df.filter(df.Column1 == col2)

        df_join = df_col1.join(df_col2, on=(df_col1.Column2 == df_col2.Column2), how="inner")
        if df_join.limit(1).count() == 0:   # No common row
            print(col1,col2,"NoCommonRow")
        else:
            print(col1,col2,"CommonRow")

However, I found that this takes a very long time to run (df has millions of rows). Is there anyway to optimize it to run faster, or is there a better way to do the comparisons?

You can do this without loops using self join as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [("abc", 111), ("def", 666), ("def", 111), ("tyu", 777),
        ("abc", 777), ("def", 222), ("tyu", 333), ("ewq", 888)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Column1", "Column2"])

result_df = (
    df.alias("a")
    .join(df.alias("b"), F.col("a.Column1") < F.col("b.Column1"), "left") # this is more efficient than the "!=" approach used in other answer because using "<" creates less rows after join (almost half) 
    .join(df.alias("c"), (F.col("a.Column2") == F.col("c.Column2")) & (F.col("b.Column2") == F.col("c.Column2")), "left")
    .where(F.col("a.Column1").isNotNull() & F.col("b.Column1").isNotNull())
    .groupBy("a.Column1", "b.Column1")
    .agg(
        F.when(F.count("c.Column2") > 0, "CommonRow").otherwise("NoCommonRow").alias("CommonStatus")
    )
    .orderBy("a.Column1", "b.Column1") # remove this if not required
)
result_df.show(truncate=False)

# Output:
# +-------+-------+------------+
# |Column1|Column1|CommonStatus|
# +-------+-------+------------+
# |abc    |def    |CommonRow   |
# |abc    |ewq    |NoCommonRow |
# |abc    |tyu    |CommonRow   |
# |def    |ewq    |NoCommonRow |
# |def    |tyu    |NoCommonRow |
# |ewq    |tyu    |NoCommonRow |
# +-------+-------+------------+

Also, please avoid the orderBy when you run this on your million-row df - use it only if necessary.

This worked on a small dataset, thanks! But I ran out of resources running this on my million-row df. Is there a way to split this up? I was thinking splitting the df into, say, 100 sets, each of 10K rows, but I would need to permutate, i.e. run the above for Set 1 and Set 2-100, then Set 2 and Set 3-100, and so on until Set 99 and Set 100. But this seems like it would be too slow. Is there a better way to do this?

Self join the dataframe to create pairs of rows
df1 = df.alias('l').join(df.alias('r'), on=F.expr("l.column1 != r.column1"))

# df1.show()
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |Column1|Column2|Column1|Column2|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+
# |    abc|    111|    def|    666|
# |    abc|    111|    def|    111|
# |    abc|    111|    tyu|    777|
# |    abc|    111|    def|    222|
# |    abc|    111|    tyu|    333|
# |    abc|    111|    ewq|    888|
# |    def|    666|    abc|    111|
# |    def|    666|    tyu|    777|
# |    def|    666|    abc|    777|
# |    def|    666|    tyu|    333|
# |    def|    666|    ewq|    888|
# |    def|    111|    abc|    111|
# |    def|    111|    tyu|    777|
# |    def|    111|    abc|    777|
# |    def|    111|    tyu|    333|
# |    def|    111|    ewq|    888|
# |    tyu|    777|    abc|    111|
# |    tyu|    777|    def|    666|
# |    tyu|    777|    def|    111|
# |    tyu|    777|    abc|    777|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+

Add a boolean flag to check whether the column2 value in left and right dataframes matches. Similarly, add a pair column which is the combination of column1 values from left and right dataframe
df1 = df1.withColumn('flag', F.expr('l.column2 = r.column2'))
df1 = df1.withColumn('pair', F.array_sort(F.array('l.column1', 'r.column1')))

# df1.show()
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+----------+
# |Column1|Column2|Column1|Column2| flag|      pair|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+----------+
# |    abc|    111|    def|    666|false|[abc, def]|
# |    abc|    111|    def|    111| true|[abc, def]|
# |    abc|    111|    tyu|    777|false|[abc, tyu]|
# |    abc|    111|    def|    222|false|[abc, def]|
# |    abc|    111|    tyu|    333|false|[abc, tyu]|
# |    abc|    111|    ewq|    888|false|[abc, ewq]|
# |    def|    666|    abc|    111|false|[abc, def]|
# |    def|    666|    tyu|    777|false|[def, tyu]|
# |    def|    666|    abc|    777|false|[abc, def]|
# |    def|    666|    tyu|    333|false|[def, tyu]|
# |    def|    666|    ewq|    888|false|[def, ewq]|
# |    def|    111|    abc|    111| true|[abc, def]|
# |    def|    111|    tyu|    777|false|[def, tyu]|
# |    def|    111|    abc|    777|false|[abc, def]|
# |    def|    111|    tyu|    333|false|[def, tyu]|
# |    def|    111|    ewq|    888|false|[def, ewq]|
# |    tyu|    777|    abc|    111|false|[abc, tyu]|
# |    tyu|    777|    def|    666|false|[def, tyu]|
# |    tyu|    777|    def|    111|false|[def, tyu]|
# |    tyu|    777|    abc|    777| true|[abc, tyu]|
# +-------+-------+-------+-------+-----+----------+

Group the dataframe by pair and aggregate with max to check if any row within a given pair group has the flag set to True
df1 = df1.groupBy('pair').agg(F.max('flag').alias('has_common_row'))

# df1.show()
# +----------+--------------+
# |      pair|has_common_row|
# +----------+--------------+
# |[abc, def]|          true|
# |[abc, tyu]|          true|
# |[abc, ewq]|         false|
# |[def, tyu]|         false|
# |[def, ewq]|         false|
# |[ewq, tyu]|         false|
# +----------+--------------+

